# Journalctl to .txt file from C program

Tags: c, linux, syslog

I have a application written in C and i want to control writing of syslogs in txt file from application. On application there is option for START/STOP running, so basically when i press START i want to start writing syslog(journalctl) to /some_folder/debug.txt, and when i press STOP i want to close the file.

This can be done by linux command "journalctl [parameter] > /some_folder/debug.txt", but that is not enough, this must be controlled from application.

Does anyone have idea how this can be done properly, is there some API to control syslogs or i have to do it via system()?

If there is no way, if i have to use system() and journalctl commands are there some suggestion which commands to use?

Comment: Have you seen [this](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/sd-journal.html)? In particular [`sd_journal_open`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/sd_journal_open.html#).

Comment: Sorry for the late answer. I have seen that, and i have managed to open journal, but now i am having problems writing it to to txt file continuously.

Idea is to simulate "journalctl -f > file.txt"